# Как, используя History API, сделать так чтобы блок, при клике на который происходит переход, сам перемещался плавно в бок?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-history-api, history-api

Как, используя History API, сделать так чтобы блок, при клике на который происходит переход, сам перемещался плавно в бок?

Comment: History API позволяет управлять историей браузера, в частности содержимым адресной строки. Этот API никак не связан с анимацией. Возможно следует отредактировать либо уточнить вопрос.

Comment: @Александр Тимофеев, и в правду, причем тут `History API`? Попробуйте воспользоваться методом `jquery.animate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> конечно то что хочешь сделать совсем не понятно но вот....

Событие `popstate` вызывается, когда изменяется активная запись истории. Если изменение записи истории было вызвано методом `history.pushState()` или `history.replaceState()`, то состояние события `popstate` будет содержать `state` копии входящего в историю объекта

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
  console.log("location: " + document.location + ", state: " + JSON.stringify(event.state));
};
history.pushState({page: 1}, "title 1", "?page=1");
history.pushState({page: 2}, "title 2", "?page=2");
history.replaceState({page: 3}, "title 3", "?page=3");
history.back(); // Logs "location: http://example.com/example.html?page=1, state: {"page":1}"
history.back(); // Logs "location: http://example.com/example.html, state: null
history.go(2);  // Logs "location: http://example.com/example.html?page=3, state: {"page":3}
```